# Perl regex matching is working weired

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to extract each language's information from MFC's *.rc file.

So, I've found "`LANGUAGE LANG_([\s\S]*?)#endif(.*)\n/{1,}`" is working for following texts at http://regexpal.com/

```
:
LANGUAGE LANG_Language1, SUBLANG_XXX
#pragma code_page()
:
END
#endif    // Language1 resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:
LANGUAGE LANG_Language2, SUBLANG_XXXX
#pragma code_page()
:
END
#endif    // Language2 resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
:
```

and also, I've programmed about regex finding through perl like this.

```
$rc_file = read_file($ARGV[0]);
@LANG = ($rc_file =~ /LANGUAGE LANG_([\s\S]*?)#endif(.*)\n\/{1,}/g);
```

and I expected to get every @LANG element forms like following texts.

```
LANGUAGE LANG_Language1, SUBLANG_XXX
#pragma code_page()
:
END
#endif    // Language1 resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

but, I'm receiving these two types.
even numbered elements are like this,

```
Language1, SUBLANG_XXX
#pragma code_page()
:
END
```

and odd numbered elements are like this.
    // Language1 resources

I cannot understand that I've used same regex but It returns without some string.
Should I wrap regex with another format? or am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try checking what's in the $1 and $2 capture groups?

Comment: Yes. i wondered why returned pattern didn't include some substrings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of unnecessary parenthesis. You got data from your groups stored in the array. Here is the working code:

```
my @LANG = ($rc_file =~ /LANGUAGE LANG_[\s\S]*?#endif.*\n\/{1,}/g);
```